# Is there a Simpler way to output a complete 'script' tag as text?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, forms

I'm writing some AJAX that pulls in a web page that has the potential to have scripts and/or css that I'm trying to separate out into a couple of supporting fields in a form that runs all of this.

I believe the pertinent code in this case is the AJAX finalizer.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var JavascriptContent = document.getElementsByName('AgendaJS')[0];
        var CSSContent = document.getElementsByName('AgendaCSS')[0];

        var Parser = new DOMParser();

        var xmlData = Parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "text/html");

        var ResponseBody = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(ResponseBody.innerHTML);

        var ResponseScripts = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('script');

        var i = 0;

        for( i = i; i <= ResponseScripts.length; i++ )
        {
            JavascriptContent.innerText += "\r\n" + String(ResponseScripts[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The idea here is to add any script tags ( preferably a direct copy of the full text ) to the 'AgendaJS' textarea.

The way I see it right now, is that I am almost bound to examining the individual elements of the script tag and regenerating the entire tag from 'scratch' - so my hope here is that I can find a manner in which to dump this element into that field that doesn't yield this:

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
```

I've glanced around at a few posts here and elsewhere that claim that a particular method works - but I am yet to confirm any of them.

To be clear - I'd effectively like the resulting addition to the JS field to be the full tag and closing tag, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try `ResponseScripts[i].text`. Though I doubt you can get the script text before appending the script to an element.

Comment: No dice - undefined. Got a solid answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResponseScripts[i].outerHTML` instead of `String(ResponseScripts[i])`

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you @friedi.

Comment: Now... Why are my line breaks getting converted to <br>s -_-

Comment: Gah - and I'm getting quotes around my script tags. Blasphemy.